# Where can I find my recent comments?

Tags: support, comments, profile-page, activity-tab

Under the my profile I can view a lot of activities that I have done like questions, answers, flags, reputation earned etc. But where can I view my history of comments that I have done.

I would like to have a glance at my comments because I just missed an important reply to one of my comments which I cannot find now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2853406/user285oo6?tab=activity&sort=comments

Comment: If you want to see *replies* to your comments, that's the "responses" tab on your profile.

Answer (score 15):

On your [user profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853406/user285oo6)

[Activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853406/user285oo6?tab=activity)

[Comments tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853406/user285oo6?tab=activity&sort=comments)

[image]

Comment: it's now in All Actions in your profile

Comment: This answer needs an update, including what @Mousey mentions above, in addition to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78591/169587

Answer (score 8):

Since the user profile page has been revamped, here's an updated image to show where to find this with the new layout:

[image]